# SQL Query for sorting and getting unique count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a table which consists of the following details

| Customer | Deal | DealStage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | D1 | Lost |
| A | D2 | Won |
| A | D3 | Contacted |
| B | D4 | Conatcted |
| B | D5 | Lost |
| C | D6 | Lost |
| D | D7 | Lost |

I have to develop a query where I should get the unique highest stage for each customer. The Stage priority is Won > Contacted > Lost. For Example, A is having three deals which are Won, Lost, and Contacted. So  I should be considering Won. Similarly Contacted for B and Lost for C and D

Is it possible to get an Output like

| Customer | Highets Stage |
| --- | --- |
| A | Won |
| B | Contacted |
| C | Lost |
| D | Lost |

By this, I can generate a pivot table that looks like

| Stage | CustomerCount |
| --- | --- |
| Won | 1 |
| Contacted | 1 |
| Lost | 2 |

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Yes of course this is possible. It is called aggregation. The first thing I'd do, though, is change the data model. Add a table for the deal stages. This has two advantages: **(1)** No typos ('Conatcted' vs. 'Contacted'), **(2)** you can add a rank column so the DBMS knows which stage ranks higher than another.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually the question was completely clear to me within seconds.  And the very rapid (and correct) 2 answers below seem to confirm this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses aggregation and `field()`:

```
select customer,
    case min(field(deal_stage, 'Won', 'Contacted', 'Lost'))
        when 1 then 'Won'
        when 2 then 'Contacted'
        when 3 then 'Lost'
    end as highest_stage
from mytable
group by customer
```

Actually we could combine this with `elt()`:

```
select customer,
    elt(
        min(field(deal_stage, 'Won', 'Contacted', 'Lost')), 
        'Won', 'Contacted', 'Lost'
    ) as highest_stage
from mytable
group by customer
```

You can then generate the final result with another level of aggregation:

```
select highest_stage, count(*)
from (
    select customer,
        elt(
            min(field(deal_stage, 'Won', 'Contacted', 'Lost')), 
            'Won', 'Contacted', 'Lost'
        ) as highest_stage
    from mytable
    group by customer
) t
group by highest_stage
```

Comment: Nice use of `FIELD`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks. `ELT()` comes handy as well, see my update.

Comment: If I wanna show the results in two columns for the year, How do I get that? I have used the field method. For Example, I should get the 2019 customer count separately in a column and the 2020 customer count separately in next column. Pl help with this @GMB

Comment: @user12490809: there is nothing in your data the relates to a date, so I can't really tell. I would recommend asking a *new question* for this, providing proper sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've edited the question. Pl check now @GMB

Comment: @user12490809: it is not a good practice to edit the question after answers were posted. This invalidates the answers, which can lead to downvotes on the answers. I would recommend rolling back your edit and asking a *new* question.

Comment: Sorry, @GMB I've created a new one. Pl check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343355/sql-query-to-sort-and-achieve-unique-count

Answer (score 0):

Use windows function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by customer 
                           order by case when dealstage = 'Won' then 1 
                                         when dealstage = 'Contacted' then 2
                                         when dealstage = 'Lost' then 3 
                                    end
        ) as rn
   from your_table t)
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye. I'll check this

Answer (score 0):

These are really two different problems.  I would, in fact, recommend different approaches to the two.  For the first, conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, 
       coalesce(max(case when state = 'Won' then state end),
                max(case when state = 'Contacted' then state end),
                max(case when state = 'Lost' then state end)
               ) as biggest_state                
from t
group by customer;
```

However, for your final result, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.state, count(*)
from t
where t.state = (select t2.state
                 from t2
                 where t2.customer = t.customer
                 order by field(state, 'Won', 'Contact', 'Lost')
                 limit 1
                )
group by t.state;
```

Note:  This assumes that the original data does not have duplicate rows.  If it does, then `count(distinct)` is one adjustment.