# SQL Query to sort and achieve Unique Count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a table which consists of the following details

| Customer | Deal | DealStage | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D1 | Lost | 2019 |
| A | D2 | Won | 2019 |
| A | D3 | Contacted | 2020 |
| B | D4 | Conatcted | 2020 |
| B | D5 | Lost | 2020 |
| C | D6 | Lost | 2020 |
| D | D7 | Lost | 2020 |

I have to develop a query where I should get the unique highest stage for each customer yearly. The Stage priority is Won > Contacted > Lost. For Example, A is having three deals which are Won, Lost, and Contacted. So  I should be considering Won. Similarly Contacted for B and Lost for C and D

Is it possible to get an Output like

| Customer | HighestStage2019 | HighestStage2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Won |  |
| B |  | Contacted |
| C |  | Lost |
| D |  | Lost |

By this, I can generate a pivot table that looks like

| Stage | CustomerCount2019 | CustomerCount2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Won | 1 |  |
| Contacted |  | 1 |
| Lost |  | 2 |

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregate as follows:

```
Select stage, 
       count(case when year = 2019 then 1 end) as year2019, 
       count(case when year = 2020 then 1 end) as year2020 
From
(Select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by customer, year
          order by case when dealstage = 'won' the 1 
                        When dealstage = 'contacted' then 2
                       else 3 end) as rn
    From your_table t) t
Where rn = 1
Group by stage;
```